# Subscribing to a newsletter without creating an account

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, newsletter

Is it possible to subscribe to a newsletter without the user having to create an account? So on a page have some fields, like email, name etc and store them in the newsletter data?

How would I do something like that?

My form code:

```
<? $pageid =  Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getId();

  if($pageid == '20'){
    echo '
    <form id="contact-form" action="https://natuurgroothandel.com/nieuwsbrief.php" method="post" class="contact_form row contact-form" role="form">
        <p class="col-sm-12 kl-fancy-form">
          <label class="control-label">Naam</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-name" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="35">
        </p>
        <p class="col-sm-12 kl-fancy-form">
          <label class="control-label">Geslacht</label>
          <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control form-control-email h5-email" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="35">
        </p>
        <p class="col-sm-12 kl-fancy-form">
          <label class="control-label">Geboortedatum</label>
          <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control form-control-phone" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="35">
        </p>
        <p class="col-sm-12 kl-fancy-form">
          <label class="control-label">Emailadres</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-phone" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="35" required>
        </p>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="error-container"></div>
        </div>
        <p class="col-sm-12">
          <button class="btn btn-fullcolor" type="submit">Verzenden</button>
        </p>
      </form>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: you need to take all required field from page and make it entry in all table that affect to this functionality.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Can you explain a little more detailed?

Comment: In default magento, when newsletter subscribe, at that time magento it self place entry in some table. You need to do same things here using custom code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to do this. Put this code in your controller action of form submission:

```
$email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email_input_name');

        $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);

        /* checking if customer is already subscribed or unsubscribed */
        if($subscriber->getStatus() != Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED &&
            $subscriber->getStatus() != Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
        )
        {
            try
            {
                $subscriber->setImportMode(TRUE)->subscribe($email);
                // return or redirect to any page you want
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have an example of this working with a form?

Comment: I used this code in an observer for order_place_after event.. you can have a simple html form with action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action') ?>" and place this code in your action method.

Comment: Alright, where can I add the above code? I got a form only on the page I want and added the line in your above comment, but I don't see the maps: module/controller/action @Sachin Agarwal

Comment: Do I need to create a module for this? I am really new to magento coding.

Comment: @twan can you please add your form code in the question?

Comment: yes I added it.